# How to auto increment the the id in postgersql?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Greeting..
 I'm trying to add objects to my PostgreSQL database everything works fine but when i add the second object in the database it only overwrite the first one

Student Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition="serial")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
public Student() {

    }

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">test123</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/hb_student_tracker</property>

        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <property name="connection_pool_size">1</property>

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

CreatStudentDemo.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        //create session Factory
        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
                .configure()
                .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();


        //create Session
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();




        try {

            System.out.println("Creating new Studnet Object..");
            //create Student Object
            Student student = new Student("Souid","Ayoub","ayoub@luv2code.com");

            //start the transaction
            session.beginTransaction();

            //save the object
            System.out.println("Saving the Student...");
            session.save(student);

            //commit the transaction
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            System.out.println("Done !");
        } finally {
            factory.close();
        }

    }
```

My table SQL

```
CREATE TABLE public.student
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('student_id_seq'::regclass),
    email character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    first_name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    last_name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT student_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.student
    OWNER to user1;
```

the first object is written fine in the database the second one will overwrite the first one

Comment: Could you show constructor of Student?

Comment: Done Bilal  check it out

Comment: when i run the first save it saves in the database but when i run a second save it will overwrite the first save in the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is using primitive type for @Id column.

Here what Hibernate says for `save()` method in javadoc;

> Persist the given transient instance, first assigning a generated identifier. (Or using the current value of the identifier property if the assigned generator is used.) This operation cascades to associated instances if the association is mapped with cascade="save-update".

`CrudRepository#save()` method checks student id, which is 0 for both first and second record, in the database. Since Hibernate founds a record and thinks you're not inserting a record, instead, you're updating a record which it's id is 0.

If you do modify your code like below, it should work;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(columnDefinition="serial")
  private Integer id;
```

Now, Hibernate will check your id and if it's a new record, id field will be null so Hibernate says this is a new record and it should be inserted as a new record.

---

Also, there is one more thing. You set `hbm2ddl.auto` in your hibernate configuration. You can check for more detail of `hbm2ddl.auto`, [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/what-are-the-possible-values-of-the-hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-configuration-and-wha).

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

In this case once `CreatStudentDemo` works, hibernate destroys your old table. That means, it deletes Student table and creates a new table. Then It creates a Student record in database as expected, let's say Student1.

Here is the thing, you rerun `CreatStudentDemo` and you expects that the second object would be inserted as Student2. However here is what really happens -- when you rerun `CreatStudentDemo` hibernate destroys the table which Student1 got deleted. Then it creates Student table and inserts Student objects with an id of 1 because this is the first record on newly created Student table.

Basicly, you can set;

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

or, you can call `save()` method for two times, like;

```
        Student student = new Student("Souid","Ayoub","ayoub@luv2code.com");
        Student student2 = new Student("Test Student","TestStudent","test@mail.com");

        //start the transaction
        session.beginTransaction();

        //save the object
        System.out.println("Saving the Student...");
        session.save(student);
        session.save(student2);
        .....
```

Comment: @Andreas you're right. Last few days,  i used Long for my objects and I did not realize he is using integer. Of course, we can use Integer, too. I am editing now -- thanks for that.

Comment: Hey bilal i've tried your solution but i still have the same problem

Comment: Actually, there is no reason to do that. Since your id is null, it's a new record. Can you check what is the id value for the first record on the database ?

Comment: Yeah , its is 1

Comment: I've just created same Student object in my own computer and it worked as expected. I don't understand why it's not working for you. You could try to print id before saving, or you could assing id 2 for your second object -- just to try if hibernate creates new records for those cases.

Comment: I've set the id of the object to 2 before saving it to the database but it has 1 in the database 
can i upload the project and provide u a link ?

Comment: Sure, I would take a look

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GtjpEmZ2Oh315QT53eQV0Wgx7dLT2q1T

get me unstuck pleas xD

Comment: Your code is working in my pc. Also, I might I understand why you're stuck. Fix me if i'm wrong, you run `CreatStudentDemo` and expect two different record in database but got only one record right ? If so, I know what is the problem andwill edit my answer, if not I'm sorry but currently I am not able to help you :(

Comment: yeah u are right , i  run CreatStudentDemo and expect two different record in database but got only one record

Comment: I name u as the "Saver of the Year"

Comment: I’m glad that help :)